# How can I convert XLSX to DOCX programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, docx, xlsx

I have a spreadsheet in an `xlsx`-file, how can I easily convert it to a `docx`-format with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to decide how to format a spreadsheet within the bounds of a document. You will have to put some thought into that task.

To do the actual conversion you can use the [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) from Microsoft. It will allow you to open the Excel file, read it, create a Word document and save it. All this without having Office installed on the computer.

If you have both Excel and Word installed on the target computer for your application you can also use [COM automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313152%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx) to directly control and automate Excel and Office. You are able to control the selection in Excel, copy the selection to the clipboard and then paste it into Word.

Comment: I've used the Open XML SDK before asking a question. But it's very difficult to open a document, parse it and create a new word document in pieces. I hope there is a simpler solution. How can this be done simply in a Word, just select, copy and paste.

Comment: Found great library: docx.codeplex.com, it is very simple to make tables in Word with it. And it does not required MS Office installed.